# How to separated the two color value

Tags: arrays, xcode, swiftui, stepper

I have a demo SwiftUI for selected two color & value as below, I want to collect the color value when user select different color.

But they're always linked same value and I cannot separate the two 'Stepper' and got them into an Array.

```
import SwiftUI

struct StepColorChange: View {
    @State private var value = 0
    let colors: [Color] = [.orange, .red, .gray, .blue, .green, .purple, .pink]

    func incrementStep() {
        value += 1
        if value >= colors.count { value = 0}
    }

    func decrementStep() {
        value -= 1
        if value < 0 {
            value = colors.count - 1}
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        // change color with value stepper
        VStack {
            Stepper {
                Text("Value: \(value) Color: \(colors[value].description)")
            } onIncrement: {
                incrementStep()
            } onDecrement: {
                decrementStep()
            }
            .padding(5)
        .background(colors[value])
            
            Stepper {
                Text("Value: \(value) Color: \(colors[value].description)")
            } onIncrement: {
                incrementStep()
            } onDecrement: {
                decrementStep()
            }
            .padding(5)
        .background(colors[value])
        
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: Brush-up on the basics of SwiftUI, see for example: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/
Use 2 variables, one for each Stepper, e.g. `@State private var value1 = 0` and  `@State private var value2 = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not rocket science here. Try something like this, using two values,
to change the stepper background color independently according each stepper value.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        StepColorChange()
    }
}

struct StepColorChange: View {
    @State private var value1 = 0
    @State private var value2 = 0
    
    let colors: [Color] = [.orange, .red, .gray, .blue, .green, .purple, .pink]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper {
                Text("Value: \(value1) Color: \(colors[value1].description)")
            } onIncrement: {
                value1 += 1
                if value1 >= colors.count { value1 = 0}
            } onDecrement: {
                value1 -= 1
                if value1 < 0 { value1 = colors.count - 1 }
            }
            .padding(5)
            .background(colors[value1])
            
            Stepper {
                Text("Value: \(value2) Color: \(colors[value2].description)")
            } onIncrement: {
                value2 += 1
                if value2 >= colors.count { value2 = 0}
            } onDecrement: {
                value2 -= 1
                if value2 < 0 { value2 = colors.count - 1 }
            }
            .padding(5)
            .background(colors[value2])
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: condensed code

```
struct StepColorChange: View {
    @State private var values = [0,0]
    
    let colors: [Color] = [.orange, .red, .gray, .blue, .green, .purple, .pink]
    
    func stepper(_ ndx: Int) -> some View {
        Stepper {
            Text("Value: \(values[ndx]) Color: \(colors[values[ndx]].description)")
        } onIncrement: {
            values[ndx] += 1
            if values[ndx] >= colors.count { values[ndx] = 0}
        } onDecrement: {
            values[ndx] -= 1
            if values[ndx] < 0 { values[ndx] = colors.count - 1}
        }
        .padding(5)
        .background(colors[values[ndx]])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            stepper(0)
            stepper(1)
            Text("stepper(0): \(values[0])") 
            Text("stepper(1): \(values[1])")
            Text("color stepper(0): \(colors[values[0]].description)")
            Text("color stepper(1): \(colors[values[1]].description)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems have too many duplication codes... I do not like this...

Comment: updated my answer with a more condense code example.

Comment: woh, what a good code! It seems so succinct and condensed ~~ Thank you!

Comment: glad I could help. You could consider accepting the answer using the tick mark next to it, it turns green.

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way, can I ask more about it? if I want to collect the value of 'stepper(ndx)' which user input, how to do about it?

Comment: you access the value for each stepper, like this:
 `values[0]` and `values[1]`, see the updated answer with the `Text(...)`.

Comment: Oh, I got it, thank you for your helping in my coding road~~ it's so important to me. Thanks @workingdog support Ukraine , by the way, I support Ukraine too.